# Fetching a single column into array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table which has column_id of type varchar2. This table may contain 1, 0 or multiple rows. My business logic depends on each case.

I am trying to fetch the column into an array but i am getting weird error (given my limited knowledge of pl/sql)

```
  TYPE t_col_id IS TABLE OF TEST_TABLE.COLUMN_ID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  AR_COL_ID T_COL_ID;
```

Then i am trying to fetch data into this array

`SELECT COLUMN_ID INTO AR_SIM_ID FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_ID = 1;`

and i am getting this error

```
Error(7,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(7,25): PLS-00597: expression 'AR_SIM_ID' in the INTO list is of wrong type
Error(7,35): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Is there something that i am missing? My original code would use this array as

```
BEGIN
   -- FETCH ARRAY QUERY
   IF (AR_SIM_ID.LENGTH = 0) THEN 
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 1
   ELSE
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 2
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         -- BUSINESS LOGIC 3
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `INTO` you must use `BULK COLLECT INTO`:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE t_col_id IS TABLE OF TEST_TABLE.COLUMN_ID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   AR_COL_ID T_COL_ID;
BEGIN
   SELECT COLUMN_ID 
     BULK COLLECT INTO AR_SIM_ID 
     FROM TEST_TABLE
    WHERE COLUMN_ID = 1;

   IF AR_SIM_ID.LENGTH = 0 THEN 
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 1
   ELSE
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 2
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 3
END;
```

But couldn't you just use `COUNT` for this scenario?

```
DECLARE
   numRows   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_ID)
     INTO numRows
     FROM TEST_TABLE 
    WHERE COLUMN_ID = 1;

   IF numRows = 0 THEN 
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 1
   ELSE
      -- BUSINESS LOGIC 2, 3, etc...
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: The thing is that my query uses at least 4 joins. The query is heavy. In case there is data (1 record) i would have to use the value of that record to `update` it. If there is multiple data then i have to update some other table for multiple occourances. If there is no data then i have to `insert` new record. So if i use count query, then in case the count is 1, I'd have to re-run the query to fetch its value so that i can update.

Comment: @x.509 ah, I see, so I take it that `BULK COLLECT` will solve your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

a. If you want to get all the rows to plsq table - you need bulk collect
b. If you just want to know how many rows there are in the table you should do:

```
 SELECT count(*) INTO v_count from TEST_TABLE where COLUMN_ID = 1;
```

c. I don't like using the EXCEPTION scope as part of the program's workflow-
I'd do:

```
IF v_count = 0 THEN  
-- BUSINESS LOGIC 1  
ELSIF v_count = 1 THEN  
-- BUSINESS LOGIC 2  
ELSE  
-- BUSINESS LOGIC 3  
END IF;
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch *. Just 1 column which could be multiple in values. and secondly, What if there is **NO_DATA** in table? a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception would be thrown and i have to write my business logic there.

Comment: first- as far as I understand, you don't want a count(distinct col) so why does it matter ? secondly- when you use count() you don't get no_data_found exception, you get 0 instead ... and third- you could always use option a - bulk collect